# VirtualBox PXE Boot - Not Receiving IP

Tags: networking, virtualbox, dhcp

I'm currently trying to clean up our imaging process by deploying and capturing a reference image to/from a VM instead of a physical machine.  Our DHCP server and SCCM/WDS servers are separate.

I'm trying to create a VirtualBox VM on my laptop that can boot to our PXE server.  So far I've gotten... absolutely nowhere.  I've tried doing a NAT connection, I've tried doing a bridge connection, and I've tried every possible adapter type with each of those.  I cannot get the VM to receive an IP from our DHCP server, which has scope options to point towards the WDS server.

If I use NAT type (and **don't** have a vmname.pxe file), then the VM picks up an IP address that is entirely external to our network.  If I use NAT type and **do** have a vmname.pxe file, then it downloads the local NBP but it still does not connect to our DHCP server.  If I use a bridge connection, then I get no DHCP or proxyDHCP offers as well.

I'm really not sure if maybe what I want to do is not possible, or if there's something I'm just doing wrong.  Any suggestions would be super appreciated.